# Firebase set function is not triggered when the app goes inactive

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I need to store an indicator of my app current activity state.

I use AppState provided by react native to track the state of the app (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html))

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      appState: AppState.currentState
    };
    this._handleAppStateChange = this._handleAppStateChange.bind(this);
  }      

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenToAppState();
  }

  listenToAppState() {
     AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange(nextAppState) {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const userID = currentUser.uid;

    if (this.state.appState.match(/active|foreground/) && nextAppState === "background") {
      console.log("App inactive ...")
      firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/live`).set(0);
    }
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active") {
      console.log("App active ...")
      firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/live`).set(1);
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }
```

When the app goes active after being in the background, the line:

```
firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/live`).set(1);
```

works just find the value is stored in the database.
Problem is when the app goes inactive the line:

```
firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/live`).set(0);
```

is not executed although the log sentence is displayed in the console.
I use Expo with react native so I tried both development mode and published version of the app and the problem still stand.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

as the document say

> inactive - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between
>   foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as
>   entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call

so when your app goes to background it first will be ***inactive*** , what you need to change is your condition , the `nextAppState` will be **inactive**

```
if (this.state.appState.match(/active|foreground/) && nextAppState === "inactive") {
  console.log("App inactive ...")
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/live`).set(0);
}
```

Comment: Ali thank you so much for your reply. Well the console prints "App inactive" which indicates that the condition is fulfilled but still the firebase call is not executed. It is like the app loses connectivity to the internet access when it is not foregrounded because sometimes (not always) when the app is foregrounded the value changes to 0 then 1 instantly and since that firebase triggers are locally saved in  case of connection loss so it can be fired once the connectivity is restored, then my conclusion is a great possibility.